# kiescanner unable to refresh rules within docker container

Tags: drools, rules, kie, business-rules

I am unable to refresh rules with latest KJAR using kiescanner. We have Artifactory as remote repository. I have provided custom settings.xml . kie-cie is in pom.xml. In docker I am providing M2-HOME.

Dockerfile
ENV APP_HOME =/app
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$APP_HOME/.m2"
ENV M2_HOME /usr/share/maven
COPY settings.xml /app/.m2/settings.xml
COPY settings.xml ${M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml

My settings.xml has artifactory url. When docker container spins up then it picks latest KJAR release from artifactory. However when I publish new version, it doesn't automatically update within the docker container. Can anyone help? Thanks.

My settings.xml has artifactory url. When docker container spins up then it picks latest KJAR release from artifactory. However when I publish new version, it doesn't automatically update within the docker container. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that:

> When docker container spins up then it picks latest KJAR release from artifactory.

Is a good sign, so that confirms the docker container can see the expected version from the external remote maven repository.

Could it be you missed to set the kieScanner to start with:

```java
// Start the KieScanner polling the Maven repository every 10 seconds
kScanner.start( 10000L );
```

To have a reproducible behavior I would advise you implement a routing/feature where you can invoke the scan manually with:

```java
kScanner.scanNow();
```

That way, you can observe the KieScanner results by your explicit invocation, and logs.

Don't forget it is ideal to set a version range, rather than relying on legacy LATEST or RELEASE (see in particular [the manual here](https://www.drools.org/docs/drools/KIE/index.html#_maven_versions_and_dependencies)).

In summary:

1. Check KieScanner is actually started
2. Consider feature to invoke KieScanner manually for reproducible and better observable behaviour
3. Use version ranges, avoid using LATEST or RELEASE for the scan coordinates as explained in the manual

Reference: https://docs.drools.org/8.35.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/KIE/index.html#_kiescanner

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I SSH into docker container and delete the maven local repository, then I see kjar picked up from artifactory. I have added listener on kiescanner and I see it logs stating running and scanning statuses. When I delete the cache then it  scans artifactory and get the Kjar. Also, version range didnt work, I get error in maven install stage itself that artifact doesnt exist so I have used LATEST keyword. I am using maven 3.0+. In my settings.xml, I have updatepolicy as always. Any other setting that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Also I havent added KJAR as POM dependency. It should picked up programatically, I think.